# Why my Windows DNS Server automatically add more TLD (.co.id) when i try to find domain using nslookup?

Tags: windows-server-2019, nslookup, dns-server, tld

When i search a domain like google.com, nslookup automatically add more TLD (.co.id) to domain that i've looking for. How to fix it?

[Screenshoot nslookup on my windows dns server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g85Py.png)

Answer (score 1):

Presumably `co.id` is configured as a search domain on the client where you are testing this.

Important to note: it is the client that appends the search domain(s) to the name the application asks for, not the nameserver. The client makes multiple queries until either one of the "improved" names exist or the actual name exists.

In this case `google.com.co.id` is apparently a name that exists, and if you have `co.id` as a search domain and look up `google.com`, then `google.com.co.id` is one of the names it will try.

Clean up your list of search domains. Choose them *carefully* if you want any at all.
(It's intended to be a way of allowing shortcuts for names internal to your own organization or similar, allowing humans to reference internal names by a short form. In this case it seems like a strange choice of search domain.)

Answer (score 0):

Your query is missing the trailing . and is therefore not a fully qualified query. In this case, nslookup appends the client's configured DNS suffixes to the query. It then "strips" or devolves the query from there. If you run nslookup in debug mode you'll see this. The key is to always use a trailing . in your query to make it fully qualified.

Long story short, what you're seeing is the normal and expected behavior of nslookup.